# How to do two-way storage mirroring between to sites inside a private network

Tags: storage, high-availability, mirroring

I am looking for a mechanism to accomplish a two-way storage mirroring.
I have two storages, both used for reads & writes at the same time.
any file wrote to one of these storages should be available for reading in the second one ASAP (the period of time should exceed no more than a few seconds).
in case one storage is down, the second one is already a full copy, and can serve any file requested.
new files should be synced to the breaking storage once it's up again.

for more case understanding here is my use case:
I am deploying an asp.net application into two sites (Site-A | Site-B), with a load balancer in between.
each site will have its own NAS storage (Storage-A | Storage-B).
Now when a user uploads a file to the application it will be saved to one storage which is linked to the site that handled the request, let's assume it was Storage-A.
Then, another user needs to download the file, but now his request handled by Site-B
means the file will be looked for inside Storage-B, and it should be available through the two-way mirroring.

Further information:
there is a 5-kilometer distance between the sites, and it's all private network and has no internet access.
network speed is 1Gb but can be increased if needed.
OS used is Windows server 2019.

I've searched a lot but all solution founds were including cloud services or clustering with one way mirroring.
happy to hear any suggestions, and pardon my deliver as it's the first question for me here.

Comment: Depending on your NAS vendor and models there should be an embedded data replication software in the NAS boxes.

Comment: I am not restricted to a specific vendor.
If there is a known vendor which provides this feature I can include it as a requirement to setup this environment.
Yet I contacted some vendors with my scenario, either they suggest working in an active-passive manner or using their cloud service.

Comment: At firs you should understand of what kind of solution you are actually looking for. Is it a free or software solution? You can also check vendors that provide SAN/Storage and NAS solutions. For, example, Netapp, IBM, HPE, DELL EMC, Hitachi and etc. Most of them also have so-called cloud-gateways that support data transfer via cloud provider.